# How do I get the current time, adjusted for daylight savings?

Tags: python, date, datetime

there are lots of questions about getting the current time, but they're not working for me

A common answer is to do the following: `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('EST'))`

This solution does not account for daylight savings. It shows now as 11pm when it should be 12pm.

How do I get the current time in python AND account for daylight savings?

Comment: You'd use the timezone `pytz.timezone('EST5EDT')`. Are you asking "How do I know whether to use EST or EDT"?

Comment: "*This solution does not account for daylight savings*" - if you use a [proper tz name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), it does. E.g. `datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))`. Also note that with Python 3.9, you have time zone handling [built into the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) and `pytz` is [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/).

Comment: Changing the timezone from EST to 'America/New_York' worked, thanky ou